# Xcode became slow at the point I cannot longer work with actual device (simulator is fine)

Tags: ios, xcode, build, sign

Since Xcode 8 beta 3, I face a situation that now prevent me from working normally and compile against actual devices (be it iPhone 7, 6s or iPad Prod, any devices actually).

Though Xcode compiling at regular pace, the stage "copying swift file to device" takes up to 15 minutes…

I saw many people facing somewhat the same situation.

Any idea?

PS : it is not related to the Swift compiler, as I saw many issue related to Swift compiling. It has to do with copying binary to or signing for a device

Comment: I've heard that there was an actual issue with code signing taking a very long time on newest macOS / Xcode. I can't provide you with a link but I did see someone coming up with a workaround for this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok I found the fix: it is related to the keychain where I had tons of Apple ID keys which I simply deleted and now it works like a charm.

Steps to fix the issue:

1) Simply open up the keychain app;

2) Get to Keys tab (see my screenshot);

3) Look for Apple ID you use to sign (typically you point at the email address that is marked as "duplicates";

4) Keep the first public key and select all the public keys duplicates and delete them;

5) Do the same wit the privates duplicates keys (keep only the first one).

Get to Xcode and simply build & run your project.

[image]

Comment: mate, you're the best. I've spent half a day trying to understand what happened to my already not so fast XCode, and specifically xcodebuild command - why all of a sudden it is as slow as dying tortoise on its trip back to Galapagos from Ibiza vacation.

nothing helped, but cleaning up the keychain worked. hope it will save somebody else's ass someday.